# Python re.search string search for open and close bracket []

Tags: python, regex

Can someone explain me why my regex is not getting satisfied for below regex expression. Could someone let me know how to overcome and check for [] match.

```
>>> str = li= "a.b.\[c\]"
>>> if re.search(li,str,re.IGNORECASE):
...    print("Matched")
...
>>>
>>> str = li= r"a.b.[c]"
>>> if re.search(li,str,re.IGNORECASE):
...    print("Matched")
...
>>>
```

If I remove open and close brackets I get match

```
>>> str = li= 'a.b.c'
>>> if re.search(li,str,re.IGNORECASE):
...    print("matched")
...
matched
```

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name as it will shadow the built-in [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to match the string `a.b.\\[c\\]` instead of `a.b.[c]`.
Try this:

```
import re
li= r"a\.b\.\[c\]"
s = "a.b.[c]"
if re.search(li, s, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("Matched")
```

`re.IGNORECASE` is not needed in here by the way.

Comment: Should i escape dot also ?

Comment: @Bhaskarvedula It's a good idea to escape the dot as `.` will match anything and `\.` will match only a `.`. It's not a must, it just makes it more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
import re
str = "a.b.[c]"
if re.search(r".*\[.*\].*", str):
   print("Matched")
```

**Output:**

```
Matched
```